# jquery helper like htmlgenericcontrol in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to build a webpage containing jquery draggables in asp.net (c#).
How can I add my jquery code to my page in an object oriented way?

So I want to make a c# myDraggables.cs class that I add to the asp page with the htmlgenericcontrol. How do I add this jquery code (eg: $('#mydraggables').draggable(); ) in my class.
I could do it with the htmlgenericcontrol by adding a "script"-tag. But isn't there a way to do it with a jquery helper (can't find that)?
tx

A sample:
Basicly, in my myDraggables-class I could have;

```
public HtmlControl Draw()
{
    HtmlGenericControl aDiv= new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    aDiv.Attributes.Add("id", "dragtest");
    return aDiv;
}

public HtmlControl DrawJquery()
{
    HtmlGenericControl js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
    js.InnerHtml = "$('#dragtest').draggable();";   
    return js; 
}
```

And the code behind of my asp.page would look like;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myDraggables md = new myDraggables ('..some props ..');
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(md.DrawJquery());
    myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(md.Draw());
}
```

That works, but jquery-code will become more complex. And will not be readable anymore...
how can this be achieved in json? Or another more readable way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to write a strongly-typed .NET class in the back-end which also functions as a jQuery object on the front-end, right? If so, the best way to do it is probably to serialize your .NET object into JSON format, store it in a variable and print it out in a script tag when generating the markup. Then, on the front-end, parse the JSON string into a Javascript object and you can use it from there.

Can you post any .NET and JS code you have already?